# Packages cannot be authenticated

Tags: 14.04, package-management, authentication

Anytime I install a new package i get the following error:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
```

I can still install the package despite this error, but is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 5):

As you clearly mentioned that you dont want to see that error in future , you can use  `--allow-unauthenticated` flag.

> --allow-unauthenticated
>
> ```
>        Ignore if packages can't be authenticated and don't prompt about
>        it. This is useful for tools like pbuilder. Configuration Item:
>        APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated.
> ```

usage:

```
apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install <package_name>
```

Hope it helps.

Credit : [Ubuntu : apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html)

Comment: Couldn't this be a security issue?

Comment: Please don't suggest that people stop authenticating packages. It'd be far better to figure out why packages are failing to authenticate.